# Unknown download on my android phone

Tags: downloading, files

8891h_01_enUs_GridClear.webp

Does anyone know what this is? There were three more like it, 4117h and 130h_01_enCA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Webp` is a file format for images. See [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webp).
Telegram uses these for stickers. It probably was downloaded from Telegram or some other app that uses this image format files.